# How to exclude a field when using a domain object for data transfer in Struts2

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2

In Struts2 it's very convenient to use domain driven in a action,however,The problem comes when the data gets automatically transferred onto the object. As we’ve seen, if the request has parameters that match the attributes on your domain object, the data will be moved onto those attributes. Now, consider the case where your domain object has some sensitive data attributes that you don’t really want to expose to this automatic data transfer, perhaps an ID,how can we exclude them? In asp.net mvc we can use exclude annotation to do it easily: `Bind(Exclude="empId")]`, do we have similar approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [`params`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) interceptor. The interceptor is a part of the `defaultStack` and you could configure it in the outer package or individually applying it on the actions. It has the property `excludeParams` and you could use this parameter to configure properties that needs to exclude from population. Along or with the support of [`ParameterNameAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParameterNameAware.html) you could separate the logic used to define accepted parameter lists and black lists. One note about `ParameterNameAware` that it is able to reveal the parameter that was excluded by the interceptor.